# RSpec success despite action and route not defined

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I have defined:

- a view at `views/pages/about.html.rb`,
- a test in `spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb`:

  ```
  describe "GET 'about'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'about'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
  ```

I have **not** defined:

- a corresponding  action:

  ```
  class PagesController < ApplicationController

    # def about
    # end

  end
  ```
- a route in `routes.rb`:

  ```
  Lily::Application.routes.draw do
    # get "pages/about"
  ```

I get an error in web browser but RSpec tests pass successfully as long as view is defined.
Is this expected behavior?

---

I'm using `rspec-rails 2.0.1`, `webrat 0.7.1` and `rails 3.2.1`.
Scott found a [similar issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/495) closed by `rspec-rails` maintainers.

Comment: Can you see whether the error page in the browser is coming in on a real, non-200, error response? You could check in FireBug / Developer Tools, or in the Rails log.

Comment: @Chowlett: I also thought this action could've somehow been cached, but it also works if I just create another view/test pair.

Comment: Sorry, that was my only idea :) I don't personally use RSpec, yet.

Comment: @DanAbramov what does response.inspect show?

Comment: @Scott: How do I pretty-print its output? It's huge in the console.

Comment: @DanAbramov does pp response.inspect work? With the requisite require 'pp' of course.

Comment: I posted unformatted output [here](http://pastebin.com/index/2j4VYBvd). I know it's ugly but I haven't found a pretty-print tool yet.

Comment: @Scott: `pp` doesn't help. Not sure why.

Comment: @DanAbramov Want to move this to the Ruby or Rails chat room?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected (perhaps somewhat surprising) behavior.

If you keep in mind how Rails separates concerns, it makes sense.
Controllers don't route—that happens in the dispatcher.

Try adding this in your test:

`raise controller.params.inspect`

```
Failures:
  1) PagesController GET pages/about
     Failure/Error: raise controller.params.inspect
     {"action"=>"about", "controller"=>"pages"}
```

`get 'about'` does not need to routed—the Rails testing framework takes care of that. Since the spec already knows what action it is supposed to handle, it goes ahead and calls `PagesController#about`.

The missing piece of the puzzle is that **Rails doesn't need an action to be defined as long as the template exists**; it will simply render `about.html.erb`.

So this test succeeds, as it should. When you call it live, it fails because there is no route. If you had written a request spec, routing spec, or a Cucumber test, it would also fail.

Comment: @zeteic Thanks. I was chatting with Dan about this yesterday in the Chat room after our exchange here. This helps make sense of what we saw during our chat.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. So there is no actual routing involved when testing with RSpec unless you test the routing itself? Makes sense. I unknowingly assumed RSpec runs a microserver and actually issues HTTP requests so this caught me by surprise.

Comment: I took some freedom to slightly change formatting in your post, sir. Hope you don't mind it but please feel free to revert if you do. I also highlighted the crucial part, that is that Rails doesn't really need an action to be defined. I just checked this the other way round—by adding the route and seeing it live without explicit action definition.

Comment: `there is no actual routing involved when testing with RSpec unless you test the routing itself?` True except for request specs, which test the whole Rails stack including the routes.